# Opening another GridPane in the same window

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

So I've got a login page. If you click on "not a user? register now!" it should open a new page in the same window. Right now I'm getting second page to open but it's in a separate window. It also creates an error message on opening the register page. here's the code:

Main

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private ConnectToDB DB;
    @FXML
    GridPane mainPane;
    @FXML
    Hyperlink RegisterHyperLink;


    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 375));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public class Controller {
    private Stage stage = new Stage();
    private GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    private boolean passwordsCheck = false;
    @FXML TextField password;
    @FXML TextField passwordConfirm;
    @FXML GridPane mainPane;
    @FXML GridPane registerPage;

    public void handleSubmitButtonAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    }
    public void goToRegisterNewUserPage(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{

        RegisterPage page = new RegisterPage(stage);
        page.getScene().getWindow().hide();
//      this is where the error gets thrown up
    }
```

Register page

```
public class RegisterPage extends GridPane {

    @FXML GridPane mainPane;
    @FXML GridPane RegisterUsers;

    public RegisterPage(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        GridPane RegisterUsers = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("RegisterUsers.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(RegisterUsers, 500, 475));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

sample.fxml for the login page as well as the relevant hyperlink

```
<GridPane fx:id="mainPanes"
            fx:controller="sample.Controller"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
<Hyperlink text="Forgot password?"
                   onAction="#goToForgotPasswordPage"/>
```

RegisterUsers.fxml is for the register users page. i'm not sure if you need this but its fx:id = registerPage. So basically clicking the hyperlink should open the Register users in the same window instead of the second. and it would be cool if it resized automatically but if not then I can do that later. I suspect the new window is related to the `page.getScene().getWindow().hide();` . I've tried a bunch of different things in the Controller. my attempt before that called the GridPane mainPane from the sample.fxml file and then `mainPane.getChildren().setAll(page);` but that also didn't work. thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Think of a `Stage` as a "Window." When you create a new `Stage` for your register "page," you're specifically telling JavaFX to open a new window. Instead, you should have a layout node in your main `Stage` that you can replace the content of.

Comment: @Zephyr I tried that but I keep getting an error on my setOnMouseClick. here's the updated start method https://pastebin.com/9W7CcC0G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely many way to accomplish this, but I've worked up a simple example.  Essentially, you'll have one `MainLayout` that only contains a single `VBox`. This is our `contentPane` for the main window.

Within that `VBox`, we'll load the `LoginLayout.fxml`. When the `Register` button is clicked, we'll load the `RegisterLayout.fxml` and replace the children of the `contentPane`.

Below is a complete example you can copy to see it in action:

**Main.java:**

```
package loginExample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/loginExample/MainLayout.fxml"));
            loader.setController(new MainController());

            primaryStage.setTitle("Login Example");
            primaryStage.setWidth(300);
            primaryStage.setHeight(200);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load()));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**MainController.java:**

```
package loginExample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private VBox contentPane;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Initially start with the login layout
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/loginExample/LoginLayout.fxml"));

            // Set the LoginController and pass a reference to the MainController. This allows the LoginController
            // to access our contentPane.
            loader.setController(new LoginController(this));

            // Now, load the login layout into our contentPane
            GridPane gridPane = loader.load();
            contentPane.getChildren().add(gridPane);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public VBox getContentPane() {
        return contentPane;
    }
}
```

---

**MainLayout.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<VBox fx:id="contentPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0"/>
    </padding>
</VBox>
```

---

**LoginController.java**

```
package loginExample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginController {

    @FXML
    private Button btnRegister;

    // Reference to our main controller so we can access its content
    private MainController mainController;

    public LoginController(MainController mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // Set our Register button to change the content of the main pane
        btnRegister.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/loginExample/RegisterLayout.fxml"));
                loader.setController(new RegisterController(mainController));

                // Set our RegisterLayout as the new content for our MainLayout window
                mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().clear();
                mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().add(loader.load());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**LoginLayout.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane hgap="10.0" vgap="5.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="NEVER"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
            <children>
                <Label style="-fx-font-size: 150%; -fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Please login below:"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <Label text="Username:" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <Label text="Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="btnRegister" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Register"/>
                <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Login"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

---

**RegisterController.java:**

```
package loginExample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegisterController {

    @FXML
    private Button btnCancel;

    private MainController mainController;

    public RegisterController(MainController mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        btnCancel.setOnAction(event -> {
            try {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/loginExample/LoginLayout.fxml"));
                loader.setController(new LoginController(mainController));

                // Set our RegisterLayout as the new content for our MainLayout window
                mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().clear();
                mainController.getContentPane().getChildren().add(loader.load());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

**RegisterLayout.fxml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<GridPane hgap="10.0" vgap="5.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="RIGHT" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0"/>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="-Infinity"/>
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="NEVER"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="-Infinity" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES"/>
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" GridPane.columnSpan="2">
            <children>
                <Label style="-fx-font-size: 150%; -fx-font-weight: bold;" text="Fill Form to Register:"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <Label text="Username:" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <Label text="Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
        <Label text="Re-enter Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"/>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" spacing="10.0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4">
            <children>
                <Button fx:id="btnCancel" cancelButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Cancel"/>
                <Button defaultButton="true" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Register"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2"/>
        <PasswordField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3"/>
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

---

**The Result:**

[image: screenshot 1][image: screenshot2]

This is a very simple example meant to demonstrate the concept; you'd likely want to structure your real world project a little differently.

Comment: How are you doing this? I keep trying to put your code in my IDE but all I get are getting error lines under every loader.load() method. plus fxml loader issues because I cannot find a suitable filepath name.

Comment: Check the location you're inputting (specifically the path in the `getClass().getResource()` method. My sample was in the `loginExample` package and yours may not be.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing on `loader.load()`?

Comment: Did you name the new files correctly? Is `sample` the root package? If you're using IntelliJ IDEA, you can right-click on the file and click "*Copy Relative Path*" to get the path you need (just add the `/` in front). It's hard to say exactly what the issue is without seeing your directory structure.